# Find out what program is using mirror drivers

Tags: windows-7, aero

I can't get access to Aero transparency themes in Windows 7. The troubleshooter says that I need to close programs that are using mirror drivers in order for that to work. I've looked through my task manager list of running applications and I can't see any that jump out as the culprit. Is there a program that will tell me what the app causing this issue is? MS Troubleshooter doesn't give me the details.

Comment: Is Windows running in a virtual machine? What are the hardware specifications?

Comment: Many assistive technology or screen magnification applications use mirror drivers. You may also have a VNC or other remote control application installed.